# automatically adjust width of columns in a "table" using div's/CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to emulate a classic table using DIVs/CSS.
In order to make the columns line up, I seem to need to specify the widths, as opposed to using a table where the column-widths are calculated dynamically depending on the content.

I will be adding more rows all the time, so it is a pain to re-optimize the widths every time (also not optimal for users on small screens).

Is my best bet just to stick with an actual table, or is there a better way?  I need something with broad support (browsers/phones/etc).

css:

```
.chart {
    background-color: green ;
    overflow: hidden ;
}
.row {
    margin-top: 5px ;
    margin-bottom: 5px ;
}
.row:after {
    clear: both ;
    content: "" ;
    display: block ;
}
.date {
    width: 3em ;
    float: left ;
}
.chap {
    width: 20em ;
    float: left ;
}
.cook {
    width: 25em ;
    float: left ;
}
```

html:

```
<p> looks like a table, but the column-widths are hard-coded, ugh.</p>
<div class=chart>
  <div class=row>
<div class=date><b>date</b></div>
<div class=chap><b>chap</b></div>
<div class=cook><b>cook</b></div>
  </div>
  <div class=row>
<div class=date>1 jan</div>
<div class=chap>intro</div>
<div class=cook>chocolate chip munchies galore</div>
  </div>
  <div class=row>
<div class=date>2 jan</div>
<div class=chap>a really big long chapter</div>
<div class=cook>none</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using DIVs to emulate a table? It looks like tabular data so you should be using an actual TABLE for it.

Comment: I'm starting to think you may be right.  Both answers are fine, but as you say it is is tabular data so the "don't use tables for layout" maxim doesn't quite apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to to this is:

css:

```
th {
    text-align: left;
    height: 30%;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
}
```

html:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
      <th>F</th>
   </tr>
</table>
```

To make it responsive wrap the table code inside the style below:

```
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">

<table>
</table>

</div>
```

Comment: I think the real answer is that my question is misguided and I should just use a table as @ThiefMaster mentions above.  Which is pretty well what this answer says.

Answer (score 0):

You can use display table, table-row and table-cell

```css
.chart {
  display: table;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.date,
.chap,
.cook {
  display: table-cell;
}

.date,
.chap {
  padding-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<p> looks like a table, but the column-widths are hard-coded, ugh.</p>
<div class=chart>
  <div class=row>
    <div class=date><b>date</b></div>
    <div class=chap><b>chap</b></div>
    <div class=cook><b>cook</b></div>
  </div>
  <div class=row>
    <div class=date>1 jan</div>
    <div class=chap>intro</div>
    <div class=cook>chocolate chip munchies galore</div>
  </div>
  <div class=row>
    <div class=date>2 jan</div>
    <div class=chap>a really big long chapter</div>
    <div class=cook>none</div>
  </div>
</div>
```